# "Restricted" access right for the "root" account in a rkt container

Tags: containers, root, sudo, rkt

I meet some issues while trying to execute commands as a root in my rkt containers.

I run the rkt engine as a sudo. Inside of the launched container, I also am logged as a root. But it seems that I am not a "real" root inside.

For example, when I try to run a "chrt" command on a launched process which I own, I get the following answer:

```
[root@rkt-b1e45e35-f3e7-4cc2-88ea-58d06809dd5d /]# chrt -p -f 99 25
Unable to change scheduling policy!
either run as root or join realtime group**
```

Other example, when I try to login as another user I created in my container, I have the following error message:

```
[root@rkt-b1e45e35-f3e7-4cc2-88ea-58d06809dd5d /]# su toto
Bad system call
```

(note: I have the same message when I try to launch a "sudo" command).

I also tried to add toto or root either to "root" usergroup or to the "realtime" one but it still does not work.

Other expressive example, when I try to apply (as a root) a `chmod +w` on a file owned by root with the following confifuration : `rw-r--r--`, I have an access denied message...

For information, a `rkt image cat manifest xxx` command on my rkt image gives the following output:

> {
>           "acKind": "ImageManifest",
>           "acVersion": "0.6.1",
>           "name": "xxxxxxxxxx",
>           "labels": [
>                   {
>                           "name": "version",
>                           "value": "latest"
>                   },
>                   {
>                           "name": "arch",
>                           "value": "amd64"
>                   },
>                   {
>                           "name": "os",
>                           "value": "linux"
>                   }
>           ],
>           "app": {
>                   "exec": [
>                           "/bin/bash"
>                   ],
>                   "user": "root",
>                   "group": "root",
>                   "workingDirectory": "/",
>                   "environment": [
>                           {
>                                   "name": "PATH",
>                                   "value": "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
>                           }
>                   ]
>           } }

Do you have any idea about the origin of my issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution : I simply had to add more "--caps-retain" parameters in the rkt run command. (per default, the local pseudo root user has strong limitations)